# Cargo rand compilation errors

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

This is a really basic question so please bear with me.

I have a project that needs to use an old build of Rust (cargo 0.19.0-nightly c995e9e 2017-03-17). It uses `rand` so I added `rand="0.4.3"` as a dependency. When the registry updates, **rand 0.5.5** (latest) is automatically downloaded and it also runs into "break loop" error which was stabilized a while ago. I am not sure how to suppress this error or make it not install the latest version.

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "hello-world"
version = "0.0.0"
authors = [""]

[dependencies]
time = ">=0.1.0"
rand = "=0.4.3"
rustc-serialize ="0.3"
histogram = "*"
```

I get this error. The repository is not cloned locally so I cannot apply the patch rust-lang/rust#37339.

> Compiling rand v0.5.5 error: break with a value is experimental (see
>   issue #37339)
>   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.5.5/src/distributions/uniform.rs:674:25
>   | 674 | break d; | ^^^^^^^ |
>   = help: add #![feature(loop_break_value)] to the crate attributes to enable
>
> error: pub(restricted) syntax is experimental (see issue #32409)
>   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.5.5/src/distributions/float.rs:71:5
>   | 71 | pub(crate) trait IntoFloat { | ^^^^^ |
>   = help: add #![feature(pub_restricted)] to the crate attributes to enable
>
> error: pub(restricted) syntax is experimental (see issue #32409)
>   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.5.5/src/rngs/mod.rs:174:27
>   | 174 | #[cfg(feature="std")] pub(crate) mod thread; | ^^^^^ |
>   = help: add #![feature(pub_restricted)] to the crate attributes to enable
>
> error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
>
> error: Could not compile rand.

What am i doing wrong? What is the right way to go about it?

Comment: Can you also post your Cargo.lock?

Comment: It's possible that you have a new version of `rand` being pulled in by another dependency. I don't know if this will work in an older Rust, but maybe try installing cargo-tree: `cargo install cargo-tree`, and see what is going on.

Comment: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/cargo-rand-compilation-errors/20141